# Edit Shop Page Sidebar

Tags: magento-1.7, layout

I'm trying to edit our shop page to include two banner images. I have edited the file in app/design/frontend/default/hellowired/layout/catalog.xml:

```
 <reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
            <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/Need-To-Store-Large-Items.pngap</src></action>
            <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog"><alt>Our customer service is available 24/7. Call us at (555) 555-0123.</alt></action>
            <action method="setLinkUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

This is not updating the left sidebar though. It's still blank. See picture.
[image]

Comment: two things 1) flush cache 2) the file extension you have in the question is 'pngap' change that

Comment: I did that. No change

Comment: Search for `<remove name="left"` in your theme XML files, maybe the left bar has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

Problems which come in my mind:

- names have to be unique throughout the whole page
- make sure the layout handle is correct

Are you sure, the template is not included or the image is not shown? Check what the actual error is.